# При возвращения указателя возвращает 0

Tags: c++, c, функции, указатели

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, после выполнения функции возвращаю указатель (который в функции имеет значение!!!). В результате в main возвращает 0. Почему?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

float* fun(int  n, float* result){
    float x=0;
    float res=0;
    for(int a=0;a<n;a++){
        if(a%2==0)
           x=pow(a,2);
        else
            x=(a-1)*a;
        float sq = sqrt(x);
        res=res+sq;
    }
    result=&res;
    return result;

}

int main(){
    int  n=20; 
    float *result;
    printf("%f",result);
    printf("\n");
    result=fun(n,result); 
    printf("%f", result);
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы возвращаете указатель *на локальную переменную*, которой после возврата из функции просто нет. И куда указывает этот указатель - Бог весть...

И компилятор должен был вас об этом предупредить.

И, кстати, выводить указатель как значение - неверно:

```
float *result;
printf("%f",result);  <-- раз здесь %f, передавать нужно
                          значение float, а не указатель на него
```

Если бы вы **сразу** задавали правильно вопрос...

```
void fun(int  n, float* result)
{
    ...

    *result=res;
}

int main()
{
    int  n=20;
    float result;
    fun(n,&result);
    printf("%f", result);
}
```

Вам надо что-то типа этого.

Comment: И как мне стоит подправить код? Может есть какие либо примеры для понимания?

Comment: Возвращать значение переменной, а не указатель. Для чего вам именно *указатель*?

Comment: Была задача создать функцию для расчета принимающая в качестве аргументов n и указатель result, который после выполнении функции надо вывести.

Comment: Создайте переменную типа `float`, передавайте в функцию ее адрес. `float r; fun(n,&r);` - и в `r` будет то, что вам нужно. См. дополненный ответ.